# Laravel Livewire dynamically creating properties in a component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

Is it possible to dynamically create properties in a livewire component for "model wiring" radio inputs, using foreach loop in mount method? I keep getting error (property not found on the component).

component:
[component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X802I.png)

view:
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnuD5.png)

Comment: use an array and define the properties in that. You can wire:model to each using the dot notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the wire model correctly

don't set value.  The value comes from the component. Use dotted notation

```
<label><div><input type="radio" wire:model="ksb.{{$key}}"></div>learning</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked! if the value is set beforehand it just 'updates' it with the value form the input. The solution was to write the model name with the dotted notation.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="Contact" class="col-form-label">learning</label>
    <input type="text" wire:model="ksb.{{ $key}}.learning" class="form-control" placeholder="learning">

    <label for="Contact" class="col-form-label">skills</label>
    <input type="text" wire:model="ksb.{{ $key}}.skills" class="form-control" placeholder="skills">

    <button wire:click="NextStep('{{ $key }}')">Next Step</button>
</div>
```

> In Component Use This

```
public function NextStep($key)
{
    $this->ksb[$key]['learning'] = '';
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).